# Want to use string to UIImage(named: String).center

Tags: ios, swift, uiimage

I created the String array called Pillar and there are 26 Strings.
I want to use that Strings in Array as a UIImage's name and set that UIImage a CGPoint.
But there is an error that UIImage does not have the member center.

The error is:

`Value of type 'UIImage?' has no member 'center'`

The code is

```
var Pillar:[String]=["Pillar1","Pillar2","Pillar3",...,"Pillar26"]
self.Pillar1.center = CGPointMake(175.0, 436.0)
self.Pillar2.center = CGPointMake(214.0, 407.0)

for(let i=3; i<=26; i++) {
    //here the error I occur
    UIImage(named: Pillar[i]).center = CGPointMake(UIImage(named:    Pillar[i-1]).center.x-5,UIImage(named: Pillar[i-1].center.y+4)
}
```

I just want to make iteration to emphasise the code by using the String array.
If not I have to write 26 lines of code. If anyone can help me please help.

Comment: You need to use a `UIImageView` and set its image property to your `UIImage`. Then you can set the image view's `center` property to where you want.

Comment: The error is telling you that a `UIImage` does not have a `center` property.  What makes you think it should?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
let images = ["Pillar1","Pillar2","Pillar3",...,"Pillar26"].map { UIImage(named: $0) }
```

And note that UIImageView has `center` property, **NOT UIImage**

Comment: Thanks for your help. But I still have an issue. I tried it like this  `let Pillar:[String] = ["Pillar1","Pillar2","Pillar3","Pillar4","Pillar5","Pillar6","Pillar7","Pillar8","Pillar9","Pillar10","Pillar11","Pillar12","Pillar13","Pillar14","Pillar15","Pillar16","Pillar17","Pillar18","Pillar19","Pillar20","Pillar21","Pillar22","Pillar23","Pillar24","Pillar25","Pillar26"].map { UIImage(imageLiteral: $0) }` and the error is -> `Cannot convert value of type 'UIImage' to closure result type 'String'`

Comment: let Pillar = ["Pillar1","Pillar2","Pillar3","Pillar4","Pillar5","Pillar6","Pillar7","Pillar8"‌​,"Pillar9","Pillar10","Pillar11","Pillar12","Pillar13","Pillar14","Pillar15","Pil‌​lar16","Pillar17","Pillar18","Pillar19","Pillar20","Pillar21","Pillar22","Pillar2‌​3","Pillar24","Pillar25","Pillar26"].map { UIImage(named: $0) }

Comment: I tested like this `let i = 3
        UIImage(named: Pillar[i]).center.x = 165.0` there still an issue like `Cannot subscript a value of type '[UIImage?]'`

Comment: Thanks, I Understand now.  I'm very glad with your help. ^^